# How to send json ouput from servlet to jsp?

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp, servlets

I'm making an inventory control. I was trying to check if the entered quantity of item is  less than the stock quantity or not. I'm getting the servet json output. But I can't send it to jsp back.

***Jsp JQuery code.***

```
<script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('#submit_btn').click((function() {
                var $name = $("select#item_name").val();
                var $qty = $("input#qty").val();

                $.post('BuyItem', {item_name: $name, item_qty: $qty}, function(data) {
                    if (data !== null) {
                        alert(text(data));
                        $("input#qty").val("");
                    } else {
                        alert("Invalid Item!");
                    }
                }
                );
            }));
        });
    </script>
```

And this is servlet query.

```
   while (rs.next()) {

                if (rs.getInt("qty") > qty) {
                    int id = rs.getInt("item_id");
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson(id);
                   // System.out.println("one" + json);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    //            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().print(json);
                } else {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String json = gson.toJson("Stock doesn\'t have enough item quantity.");
                  //  System.out.println("two" + json);
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    //          response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().print(json);
                }
            }
```

From both System.out.println() s output is always coming correctly. But not sending to jsp back. Please help me with this.

Comment: Tried `response.getWriter().write(json)`?

Comment: double (()) in js click function

Comment: as @PramodKarandikar suggested send json back not text

Comment: @Pramod Karandikar tried,, no responce to jsp

Comment: @madalin ivascu what? can u explain please?

Comment: @madalinivascu not not that too

Comment: you are printing the json twice : one with system out and one in response

Comment: ok. I commented the sout. Still not responding  Now what?

Comment: Why `alert(text(data))` and not `alert(data)`? Unless you have a `text()` function somewhere in scope, it will throw an error.

Comment: :) I'm sorry to say.. I removed text part too.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do and also a best practice is to create a DTO class with the properties that you need to pass to gson library.

```
    public class ResponseDTO implements Serializable{
          private Integer id;
          //more properties ...

          public Integer getId() {
            return id;
          }
          public void setId(Integer id) {
              this.id= id;
          }  

           // other getters & setters
   }
```

and inside your loop, set the values to the dto object, then pass it to gson.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
          ResponseDTO dto = null;
          String json = "";
          response.setContentType("application/json");
          ......
          if (rs.getInt("qty") > qty) {
                dto = new ResponseDTO();
                int id = rs.getInt("item_id");
                dto.setId(id); 
                ......

                json = gson.toJson(dto);            
            } else {
               ...... // similar
                json = gson.toJson("{data: 'Some message'}");
            }
        response.getWriter().print(json);
```

gson will give you the proper json structure to the client side.
try and see !

Comment: what is your actual problem? is n't it "How to send json ouput from servlet to jsp?"   ???

Comment: just modified my code, try with the dto approach, and let me know the output you get for "data" in client side.(I assume your query returns proper result/data)

Answer (score 1):

Gson allows strings and numbers to serialize to JSON by themselves (which is probably ok by the definition), but a lot of other libraries would consider this invalid JSON.

Try wrapping your response in an object so that the response is `{"id": 5}` and not just `5`.

Comment: you mean like this.? String json = gson.toJson("id":rs.getInt("item_id")); Or can you explain more.?

Comment: You could do something like that, but it's a bit dirty. To make it work, wrap the whole thing with `{}`

Comment: On second thought, that wouldn't solve it. What you need to do is wrap the result in an object, like map or array.

Comment: For example: `Map myMap = new HashMap(); myMap.put("itemId", rs.getInt("item_id"); gson.toJson(myMap);`

Comment: and how do actully jquery take this form jsp page?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it's something like: `$.parseJSON(data).itemId`