# How to pass arraylist and string using json

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, servlets

I'm trying to pass an array list and string using ajax/json request. String is going to be set textfeilds and list should set in already defined table's  tags.

Here is the code.

```js
var $myValue = $(this).attr("data-myAttribute");
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                        url: "CasualLeaveController2",
                        data: $myValue,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if(data!=null){
                        var values = data.split(",");
                                $('#employee_no').val(values[0]);
                                $('#epf_no').val(values[1]);
                                $('#employee_name').val(values[2] + " " + values[3]);
                        }
                        else {
                        alert("No results");
                        }
                    }


                });
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:75%" align ="center" id="mytable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Entitlement Day</th>      
                                <th>No Of used Days</th>
                                <th>Bal Avb. Days</th>
                                <th>Pending Days</th>
                                <th>Available Days</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                <td id="entitled">$$</td>
                                <td id="used">$$</td>
                                <td id="bal">$$</td>
                                <td class="pending" data-toggle="modal" id="pend">$$</td>
                                <td class="avb_days" id="avb">$$</td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
// more code 

    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Employee No.</label>  
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"   id="employee_no" readonly/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>EPF No.</label>  
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"   id="epf_no" readonly/>
                        </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Employee Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" readonly id="employee_name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my servlet method.

```
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("personid"));
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            int year = Integer.parseInt(sdf.format(date));
            CasualLeaveService service1 = new CasualLeaveServiceImpl();
            Employee emp = service1.getEmployee(id);
            List <LeaveSummary> list1 = service1.getSummery(id, year, LeaveType.CASUAL);
            String json = new Gson().toJson(emp.getEmployeeNo() + "," + emp.getEpfNo() + "," + emp.getOtherNames() + "," + emp.getSurname()+","+list1);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            out.write(json);

        }
    }
```

Data is coming from db. I tried it. But I can't display whole this information. Help me.
I can't use append method because there are some special class tags in some  s. So please help me sort out this mess. 
Please.

Comment: Is your json sent from the server? Can you show us a sample of the json sent to the browser?

Comment: This code is jsp to server. and server to jsp. Thats all I have

Comment: Its actually html to servlet. Jsp executes on the server sending html and javascript to the browser. The client interacts with the html and js and sends a new request back to the server. A subtle but important distinction.

Comment: Can you post the json that is sent by the server as part of the ajax response?

Comment: I added the server code @ramp. I'm sorry I'm not very fluent in this json subject.

Comment: ok, can you just do this? String json = "..''; System.out.println(json); and print the output here.

Comment: I get number format exception=null

Comment: That means your code does not even reach the line where the json is generated. You need to debug that and find out the cause of the exception and then proceed.

Comment: Hey I have made some changes to code.. Can I update it? So it no longer json. but all strings are coming. List also displaying from "toString()" method?

Comment: without creating a String and pass to GSON, create a DTO object and pass it to your gson.toJson(Object). Then you can handle it in client side very easily rather than doing complex manipulations to handle strings.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva can u give me an example. pl

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/gson-example-read-and-write-json.html use this example

Comment: @DiliniRathnayake, matti.. I have written a similar answer to another question. please read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691204/how-to-send-json-ouput-from-servlet-to-jsp/29692314#29692314

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva matto.. Inna mata diwas ne.

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva matto.. I can't try this at the moment. Mama meka ahala wath ne. So I'll try this tonight and accept this answer. Thank you so much for your support. :)